# Schemes as categories fibered in thin groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, schemes, fibration, fibered-categories

Every time I start to read about schemes from a birds-eye view (like in the introduction to [The Geometry of Schemes](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/eisenbudharris.pdf) by Eisenbud and Harris) I get really excited; they sound like a categorical approach to geometry, allowing for a rigorously formalized account of the infinitesimal which almost directly permits one to formalize their intuition about infinitesimal geometric concepts and then reason about these concepts precisely in an intuitively satisfying manner.

By the time I get to the formal introduction, however, we're immediately talking about prime ideals of commutative rings and topological spaces -- I have no problem with these concepts in a vacuum, but this approach feels far off base from the expectations outlined above. I have no doubt that category theory is hiding nearby in the background, but  the approach through commutative algebra and topology is off-putting to me.

In the midst of my despair I came across Martin Brandenburg's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1053477/232121) to a question over at MSE where he says that 'schemes are categories fibered in setoids', however the page of the Stacks project linked in the answer makes no reference to schemes. In the comments on this same answer he outlines how the category of setoids is isomorphic to the category of thin groupoids, which leads to the following

> **Proposition.** A scheme is a category fibered in thin groupoids; that is, a [Grothendieck fibration](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration) $p:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{B}$ whose fibres are all thin groupoids.

Since Grothendieck fibrations aren't the fibrations in the model structure on $\mathfrak{Cat}$, we may want instead to offer the following

> **Proposition.** A scheme is a category essentially fibered in thin groupoids; that is, a [Street fibration](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Street+fibration) $p:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{B}$ whose [essential fibres](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/essential+fiber) are all thin groupoids.

Either of these points of view would be very appealing to me.

> *Question*: Are either of these propositions correct, and if so are there any introductions to the theory of schemes viewing them in this light?

Comment: “Is a” is highly misleading here. Every scheme is a category fibred in setoids, sure. But so is any presheaf, not necessarily satisfying any sheaf condition, let alone representability by a scheme.

Comment: @ZhenLin So all schemes are categories fibered in thin groupoids, but not all categories fibered in thin groupoids are schemes?

Comment: Schemes are categories fibered in setoids . . . over the category of schemes (or affine schemes, if you want something “smaller”).

Comment: You can describe the category of schemes without using the fully faithful embedding in the category of locally ringed spaces, just as you can describe the category of complex analytic spaces without using the fully faithful embedding in the category of locally ringed spaces over $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}$, just as you can describe the category of smooth manifolds without using the fully faithful embedding in the category of locally ringed spaces over $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{R}$.  If you want to compare these categories, it is convenient to use these embeddings.

Comment: @JasonStarr I'm pretty much completely unfamiliar with the theory of schemes; what is a scheme if not a locally ringed space? Presumably you refer to the [equivalence mentioned on the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/scheme#translation_between_the_two_approaches), so by 'category of schemes' do you mean 'category of $k$-schemes for arbitrary commutative rings $k$'? Or do you mean a presheaf on the opposite of the category of commutative rings with identity?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The two approaches define the same category up to equivalence if you are scrupulous about size issues. The functor of points approach is based on sheaves of sets on a site; presheaves of sets can equally well be viewed as discrete fibrations; and discrete fibrations are up to equivalence the same as fibrations whose fibres are setoids. This is what Martin's comment is about. If I may be frank: you should bite the bullet and pick some concrete definition and learn it. There is no compromise-free beautiful high-concept definition.

Comment: There are several different categories, all of which are equivalent, and all of which are commonly referred to as the category of schemes.  One of these is the full subcategory of the category of locally ringed spaces whose objects are locally isomorphic to those locally ringed spaces representing a contravariant functor sending each locally ringed space to the set of ring homomorphisms from a fixed commutative unital ring to the ring of global sections of the structure sheaf.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm sure I'll eat lead on this one eventually, but for the time being there are other things I need before the machinery of schemes becomes relevant to my research program. I'm holding on to hope in the interim that the machinery involved in $2$-categorical Galois theory will eventually provide a 'natural feeling' definition of schemes, and consequently sensitive to definitions like the one Martin appeared to be giving, but if a suitable royal road hasn't cropped up by the time I need schemes I'll plow through the weeds as necessary.

Comment: I find your opening paragraphs very peculiar.  It seems like you’re approaching this assuming that “a rigorously formalized account of the infinitesimal which almost directly permits one to formalize their intuition about infinitesimal geometric concepts and then reason about these concepts precisely in an intuitively satisfying manner” must *a priori* mean something built from pure category-theory, rather than topology or commutative algebra.  Category theory gives a fantastic toolbox and philosophy, but it’s not the be-all and end-all of maths!

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I've never taken a real crack at classical algebraic geometry, but my laymans understanding is that there was a long period last century where the experts had an intuition for 'how things should be' but the formalized methods in the field were far away from this intuition, ultimately requiring a good deal of hand-waving that was alleviated by Grothendieck et. al. with the introduction of schemes. I don't view category theory as an end all-be all for mathematics, I'm just elbow deep at the moment and wondering how far it can be pushed to understand interesting concepts.

Comment: @AlecRhea Well, take it from someone who lived underwater in the ocean of category theory and wrote a thesis on how to construct the category of schemes: it cannot be done. People who claim there is an elegant definition are cheats: either they throw away some class of schemes  they say are not worth caring about, or they allow some things that are not really schemes but they do want to think about, or both at once. [My thesis](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/256998) would be only a dozen pages long if it could really be done as easily as people say.

Comment: Grothendieck's introduction of schemes did not just clear up careless prior work in algebraic geometry.  In the introduction of EGA, Grothendieck presents a roadmap for how the theory of schemes will help prove the Weil conjectures.  If you are looking for something to help understand the definition of schemes using locally ringed spaces, it might help to choose some specific application of the theory of schemes and see how the definition helps with that application.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you for the reference; these things are indeed more complicated than they seem at first blush.

Comment: @JasonStarr I will probably have to do just that; right now my interest is primarily because the theory looks general enough that it will apply to contexts I care about when I reach them, but I haven't reached those contexts yet.

Answer (score 5):

This is essentially the [functor of points](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor%20of%20points) approach to schemes.

Define the site AffSch of affine schemes as the opposite
category of commutative rings, equipped with the Zariski Grothendieck topology.
Concretely, the poset (locale) of opens of the Zariski spectrum
of a commutative ring R can be identified with the poset of radical ideals of R; open covers are given by collections of radical ideals in R that generate an ideal whose radical equals R.

Consider the category S of sheaves of sets on the site AffSch.
Various objects considered in algebraic geometry, such as schemes and algebraic spaces, form full subcategories of S.
Concretely, [schemes can be characterized as objects of S that admit an atlas](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26506/categorical-construction-of-the-category-of-schemes/26516#26516),
i.e., a family of open immersions from affine schemes such that the induced map from their coproduct is an epimorphism.
The nLab has [another characterization of schemes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/scheme#as_sheaves_on_), see Definition 2.4 there.

The 2-categories of thin groupoids and sets (the latter with identity 2-morphisms) are equivalent.
Thus, sheaves of sets on AffSch (equivalently, categories fibered in sets over AffSch) can be replaced with the equivalent 2-category of categories fibered in thin groupoids over AffSch.

The cited [answer by Martin Brandenburg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053082/why-thin-groupoids-are-not-ubiquitous/1053477#1053477)
gives an example when such an adjustment is (marginally) useful,
since it allows us not to take isomorphism classes for certain constructions.

A lot of books cover the functor of points approach in some way, including Vakil's [modern exposition](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/).
Among the more classical sources one can point to Demazure and Gabriel's Introduction to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Groups (North-Holland, 1980).

Comment: Thank you for the references, I’ll give them a look.

Comment: @Dmitri I think you are sweeping some subtleties under the rug with your definition of atlas. How do you exclude algebraic spaces that are not schemes?

Comment: @ZhenLin: This was discussed on MathOverflow before, I added a hyperlink to the original answer with this definition.

Comment: I don't know whether my understanding is correct. Let $\mathscr F$ be a sheaf on the big Zariski site of affine schemes. Then $\mathscr F$ is representable by a scheme if and only if the natural map $\operatorname{colim}_{h_A\to\mathscr F}h_A\to\mathscr F$ of Zariski sheaves is an isomorphism, where $h_A$ is the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\cdot)$ represented by the ring $A$, and the colimit is taken along all open immersions. If we replace open immersions by étale maps representable by schemes, we get algebraic spaces?

Comment: I "learned" this from [Scholze's Lecture notes on Analytic Geometry](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf) Definition 13.5, which seems a bit neater since it does not directly involve any special choice. In some sense, this index category of open immersions $h_A\to\mathscr F$ is an analogue of maximal atlas in differential geometry.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov That's better. Your original post did not mention the condition that the individual pieces of the atlas are open immersions, which is crucial if you want to define schemes but not algebraic spaces.